# React onClick custom function

Tags: reactjs

I want to have a function that can return a button with onClick equal to some custom function you can pass in. Here's what I have so far. When I click on it, nothing happens. Here is the code that for the button

```
function Button({text,bgcolor,func}){
  return <button onClick={func} style={{backgroundColor:bgcolor, color:"white"}}>{text}</button>
}
```

and here's the code I'm using to make it

```
<Button text="alert" bgcolor="red" value="()=>alert('test')" />
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? This looks like it should work.

Comment: Here's some more code for context, <Button text="alert" bgcolor="red" value="()=>alert('test')" />  when I click on the button, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Also, when I inspect it, there isn't the value of onClick, just style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a string, not a function. Also, the prop `value` doesn't equal to the prop `func`, expected by `Button`. Just write:

```js
<Button text="alert" bgcolor="red" func={()=>alert('test')} />
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked, I'm not sure why I didn't think of that :(

Comment: My pleasure! Please mark this answer as valid if it suits you, so other people can benefit from a resolved thread.

Comment: I will, it's not letting me right now, it says wait one minute :)

Comment: Sorry to bother, but I also have another question, I want to have an variable update, so if I change it, then it will show up as that value, how would I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. But if you want to update a prop in your child  component, just pass a dynamic value in the parent with curlybraces instead of a string.

Comment: For example, in the answer above, if instead, alert('test') would've been foo=21 when foo was originally 20, and you have an element using foo, then how would you make the variable update to show 21 instead of 20?

Comment: Never mind! I just needed to change something using a little bit of javascript and innerHTML, tysm for all the help, "Godfather"! ;)